# Finding cause of object disposed exception with OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

Our company is using OWIN with ASP.NET MVC 5 and one of our developers is getting the following stacktrace at seemingly random times; however, I cannot reproduce the issue. I'm using SimpleInjector, but don't think this is related to it even though that line 118 in the stacktrace is the following:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => {
    using (container.BeginExecutionContextScope())
    {
        await next();
    }
});
```

The other suspicious part is the reference to this in the stacktrace

`Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapWhenMiddleware`

I have a MapWhen configured like this

```
app.MapWhen(c => c.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/api/mobile")),
        api =>
        {
            ConfigureBearerApps(api, ValidateMobileIdentity);
        });
```

StackTrace:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker'.
   at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.CheckDisposed()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.<InvokeCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapWhenMiddleware.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at MyProject.Startup.<>c__DisplayClass21_0.<<ConfigureIoc>b__1>d.MoveNext() in Y:\src\MyProject\Startup.cs:line 118
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.<DoFinalWork>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Is there any additional logging I can enable to find the cause?

Comment: Could it be because the calling client has terminated it's TCP connection? Do these occur in controlled tests, or are they happening in your live service? Is the stack-trace always the same?

Comment: @RB thanks for the suggestion. I don't believe this is where the issue is. This happens only locally on the developers machine, for now (we are yet to deploy a large underlying change we made to use OWIN throughout). We're not seeing the issue in our staging environment, so that's a good sign.
Yes, the stack-trace is always the same.

Comment: Found this interesting article: https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/2091

It says to not use IAppBuilder.UseWebApi(config) when hosting in IIS. Then, this article basically contradicts it: http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/discussions/540202

I'm not sure which to believe. Anyone have some insight?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you've implemented `IDisposable` on the object you're injecting, and then somewhere, you're calling `Dispose` on it. When using dependency injection, the container owns the instance and is responsible for disposing of it. The code you've posted doesn't provide any guidance as to where this might be occuring, so I would simply do a search for `Dispose` in your project and step through the results until you find something suspicious.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's easier said than done, but it's a good one and I'll poke around to see where it could be.

Comment: If you're using dependency injection, explicit calls to `Dispose` should be few and far between. The only reason to call `Dispose` would be if you didn't inject something, and then that begs the question of why aren't you injecting it?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the fact that I am setting ASP.NET Identity stuff in the CreatePerOwinContext in my Startup like this:

 app.CreatePerOwinContext(AuthDbContext.Create);
 app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
 app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
 app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);

which then gets disposed in a base controller. I probably don't need to dispose of them, right?